# Assigning HTML content to a var in Google Spreadsheet Script

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to execute an automail through a script in **Google Spreadsheet** to mail all my clients at a single time. But every time I'm trying to run the script it says that I've incorrectly assigned the HTML content to a variable.

The script code for assigning the value was :

```
function sendMail(){

  var name = 1;
  var email = 2;
  var userEmail = 3;
  var password = 4;

  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("MailApp");
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Copy of OneDrive Cloud Storage");

  var data = ws.getRange("B2:E" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

  data.forEach(function(row){
    emailTemp.name = row[name];
    emailTemp.userEmail = row[userEmail];
    emailTemp.password = row[password];
    emailTemp.email = row[email];

    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();

    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      row[email],
      "OneDrive 5TB Storage",
      "Your email doesn't support HTML.",
      {name: "AutoMail by Shovon", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
    );
  });
}
```

An error was in the line: `var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();`
The error message says :

[image: Error Message]

I'm also attaching the HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Dear <b> <?= name ?>, </b> </p>
  <p>I received your <b>OneDrive 5TB Cloud Storage</b> request yesterday. I'm really very sorry for being so late as I had some personal things to do.</p>
  <p>But the good news is I've successfully created the following <b>OneDrive Business Account</b> for you: </p>
  <p> User email:<b> <u><? = userEmail?> </u> </b> <br>
   Password: <b> <?= password?> </b> </p>
   <p> Please login to this <b> Microsoft</b> account as soon as possible and set up 2 steps verification method by using your own email address(e.g. <b> <u> <?= email ?> </u> </b>).</p>
   <p>To login <b> <u> <a href = "https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1590813490&rver=7.0.6738.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https:%2F%2Faccount.microsoft.com%2Fauth%2Fcomplete-signin%3Fru%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccount.microsoft.com%252F%253Frefp%253Dsignedout-index%2526refd%253Dwww.bing.com&lc=1033&id=292666&lw=1&fl=easi2">click here</a></u></b>.</p>
   <p>Yours,<br>
   <b>Md. Shahariar Shovon</b></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Please help me solving this issue.**

Comment: This `var data = ws.getRange("B2:E" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();` should be `var data = ws.getRange("B2:E" + ws.getLastRow()-1).getValues();`

Comment: If name is in column B then this `var name = 1;` should be this `var name = 0;` and all of the others need to be decreased by one.  Arrays starting numbering from zero columns start at 1 and your range starts at columnB and you only have 4 columns so they should be 0,1,2 and 3 for indexes

Comment: My first column was timestamp and I skipped it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
<? = userEmail?>
```

should be

```
<?= userEmail?>
```

So the app script tries to eval javascript code "= userMail" instead of simple "userMail" which is apparently invalid

Answer (score 0):

You don't need HtmlService, as "The HTML service lets you serve web pages that can interact with server-side Apps Script functions." and that is its use case.

So just create the HTML using JavaScript and then place it into the body. For example, picture this in your `for` loop.

```
const infoObj = {
  name: row[name],
  email: row[userEmail]
}
const emailBody = createEmailBody( infoObj );
const params = {
   name: "AutoMail by Shovon",
   htmlBody: emailBody.html
}

GmailApp.sendEmail(infoObj.email, subject, emailBody.plain, params);

// here you can create your html body
function createEmailBody( info ) {
  return {
    plain: `Hi ${info.name}, this is your ${info.email}`,
    html: `<div>Hi ${info.name}, this is your email ${info.email} </div>`
  }
}
```